# Strange crash on iOS 4.3.5

Tags: objective-c, ios

SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR

Here's stacktraces (according to crittercism)

Crashed thread:

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib 0x33b75c98 objc_msgSend + 15
1    Foundation 0x34ce5389 -[NSThread main] + 44
2    Foundation 0x34d575cd __NSThread__main__ + 972
3    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Other threads:

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x36888dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
5    GraphicsServices 0x3604241f GSEventRunModal + 114
6    GraphicsServices 0x360424cb GSEventRun + 62
7    UIKit 0x35732d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
8    UIKit 0x35730807 UIApplicationMain + 670
9    (app name) 0x3b97 main (main.m:8)
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c7fbc kevent + 24
1    libdispatch.dylib 0x33799041 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 92
2    libdispatch.dylib 0x337985f1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 192
3    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34601591 _pthread_wqthread + 264
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x36888dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
5    WebCore 0x36051285 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 388
6    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x36888dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
5    Foundation 0x34cf27fd +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 212
6    Foundation 0x34ce5389 -[NSThread main] + 44
7    Foundation 0x34d575cd __NSThread__main__ + 972
8    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x368cb6d9 CFRunLoopRun + 48
5    (app name) 0x0001e04b +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4791)
6    Foundation 0x34ce5389 -[NSThread main] + 44
7    Foundation 0x34d575cd __NSThread__main__ + 972
8    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c6c60 __select + 20
1    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c6d18 __semwait_signal + 24
1    libsystem_c.dylib 0x345ceeb9 pthread_cond_wait + 32
2    CoreMedia 0x313578fb WaitOnCondition + 10
3    CoreMedia 0x31357841 FigSemaphoreWaitRelative + 72
4    MediaToolbox 0x3336ba6b fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 54
5    CoreMedia 0x313754e3 figThreadMain + 162
6    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x36888dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
5    MapKit 0x313a345d _ZN16TileCachePrivate14runCacheThreadEv + 280
6    MapKit 0x313a3341 _ZL15_runCacheThreadPv + 8
7    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c6d18 __semwait_signal + 24
1    libsystem_c.dylib 0x345ceeb9 pthread_cond_wait + 32
2    QuartzCore 0x30dcb737 _ZN2CA13DispatchGroup6threadEPv + 90
3    QuartzCore 0x30de583d thread_fun + 16
4    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c4c00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1    CoreFoundation 0x368f62bf __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 94
2    CoreFoundation 0x368f8569 __CFRunLoopRun + 356
3    CoreFoundation 0x36888ec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
4    CoreFoundation 0x36888dcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
5    MapKit 0x313ae215 +[NSThread(MKAdditions) _mapkit_runThread:] + 340
6    Foundation 0x34ce5389 -[NSThread main] + 44
7    Foundation 0x34d575cd __NSThread__main__ + 972
8    libsystem_c.dylib 0x34600311 _pthread_start + 248
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c73ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
```

Thread: Unknown Name

```
0    libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x345c73ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
```

Will be grateful for any suggestions how to fix this crash.

Comment: we need to see some code

Comment: Code only helps if the developer knows roughly where the crash happens. He did not indicate that this is known and the crash report doesn't give a hint on the location either, and also can't.

Comment: It would help to know if you have tried Instruments, Dtrace, or any of the built in memory debugging tools.

Answer (score 3):

This crash happens because of a memory leak or zombie object. You are releasing an object which later on is accessed on the main thread. Best way to track this down is to use instruments leaks detection or NSZombie.

The leak could be anywhere in your app, the crash report can't give you a lot of help on that.